# Oracle18C fail to open PDB after Windows 10 reboot

Tags: oracle

Oracle18c, I created a CDB then a PDB inside. Everything worked fine until I restart my Windows. I couldn't connect to my PDB anymore.

so I connect to my CDB with my SYSTEM account, and show DB stats

```
#show pdbs;

3 TCP18DB                        MOUNTED
```

I found that I  need open the PDB:

```
#ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE tcp18db open ;
```

I get following error message

```
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE tcp18db open 
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

This confused me as I connect as SYSTEM account this should be DBA and get all privilege as I understand.

Comment: The DBA role has most privileges, but doesn't include the SYSDBA or SYSOPER system privileges. More info: http://momendba.blogspot.com/2007/07/closer-look-at-sysdba-and-dba.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an account that is allowed to connect as SYSDBA - which is the SYS account, e.g.:

```
sqlplus sys/yourpassword as sysdba
```

To make the PDB mount automatically you should also run

```
alter pluggable database tcp18db save state;
```

once you have started it. Then it will be started automatically with the next reboot.